# Using Ridder to find root

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Im trying to use ridder to find the root of my complex function however to find the root I need I must first shift the axes of my plot.
Here is what ive done so far I am trying to find t when v = 335

```
##part a 
import math as m 
from math import log
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.arange(0,250,0.1)
n = 13.3*10**3
M = 2.8*10**6
g = 9.8
u = 2510
plt.plot(u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*t))))-g*t-335, t, 'r-^') ##'-335' so that the root is now t when v=335
plt.xlabel('velocity')
plt.ylabel('time')
plt.show()


#using ridder   
import error 
from ridder import *
def f(x):
    return (u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*t))))-(g*t))-335
print "root =",ridder(f,-50,100)   ##using range of approximate times pulled from plot
raw_input("press return to exit")
```

Ive also got a value error but I don't that will matter once ive shifted my axes
I have now shifted my axes but my code for ridder keeps giving me this error
 "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. use a.any() or a.all()" 
What have I done wrong and how do fix it ?

Comment: Where does `ridder` come from? Does it refer to `scipy.optimize.ridder` or something else?

Comment: Thanks for replying and yes it does

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your function `f` accepts an `x` parameter but doesn't actually use it for anything. Furthermore, it needs to return a scalar, but returns a vector instead (because `t` is a vector). Perhaps you meant `u*(np.log((M)/(M-(n*x))))-(g*x)`?

Comment: no I do mean t unfortunately

Comment: What you're currently doing makes no sense. You are trying to find a value of `x` for which `f(x) == 0`, but your expression for `f(x)` doesn't depend on `x`.